# Is it possible to use @import in Adobe AIR CSS?

Tags: css, import, air

Trying to use @import url('myfile.css'); in my css file in Adobe AIR but it's not working.

I have tried variations such as url('file:///myfile.css') and url('file:///abs/path/myfile.css') and none of it seems to be working.

Comment: No one has an answer? :/

Comment: sorry, i dont have an answer, being an explorer into the land of Air, but favoriting this as I am sure I'll come across this issue some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me, simply:

```
@import 'myfile.css';
```

If this doesn’t work (remember, that the path is relative to the CSS file, or HTML document if it’s in a `style` tag), try using the `app://` prefix, because that’s the correct path to your projects document root.